# How do I store a dynamically changed textbox value as a checkbox value?

Tags: java, html, jsp, checkbox

I have a table that displays data from a database. The table has 3 columns, first one being the Checkbox.

```
<sql:setDataSource var="datasource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/PhoneBookDB" user="root"
    password="12345" />

<sql:query var="pbook" dataSource="${datasource}">
    SELECT * FROM phoneBook
</sql:query>

<html:form action="/PhoneBookAction.do" method="post"  >        
    <table align="center" bgcolor="Khaki" border="5" bordercolor="SaddleBrown" cellpadding="10">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" ><b>Select</b></td>
                <td align="center" ><b>Name</b></td>
                <td align="center" ><b>Phone Number</b></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

<c:forEach items="${pbook.rows}" var="row">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" align="middle" name="record" value="${row.id},${name},${pNum}"> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" value="${row.c_name}" >  </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="pNum" maxlength="10" value="${row.p_num}">   </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>

    </table>
    <html:submit property="method"  value="Edit"  />    
    <html:submit property="method" value="Delete" />
</html:form>
```

I want users to be able to **UPDATE** the values of columns **Name** and **Phone Number** from the JSP itself. I have no clue about how I can set the **updated value** in the textbox to the **checkbox's value attribute** , so that the updated value can be sent to a servlet and then a model, for operation on the DB.
 I want to solve this without using JavaScript.
 Kindly help! Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the row id as a value of the checkbox. Do not append name and pNum on the checikbox value.

On submit, in your action class, append the name and pNum to the rowId as required.

I hope this will help. I do not see any point in appending the name and pNum to the row.id as a checkbox value in the jsp page itself.

Comment: Hi, @Deepak Thank you for the reply. I need to pass the name and pNum from the JSP because I want to perform an **UPDATE** on the database. Could you please elaborate on appending the name and pNum in the action class? As I understand this would require a `request.getParameterValues("name");` in a for loop ?

Comment: On your servlet/ Acton class, do request.getParameter() for all the attributes and append them separated bu comma. You will get the required String value.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix the problem.                         `<input type="checkbox" align="middle" name="record" value="${row.id}">`   in the JSP and         `request.getParameter("name_" + record[i])`  `request.getParameter("pNum_" + record[i])`  in the Action class.